# Get last used directory

Tags: c#, .net, directory, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

when the SaveFileDialog opens for the first time it has an initial directory. I would like to get that path.

And also if I go into C:\Temp and save a file. Next time I open the SaveFileDialog the program will remember this. I would like to have this path also. Or do I have to save this manual in my program?

Best regards
R

Answer (score 4):

You have to set [`FileDialog.RestoreDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory.aspx) to `true`.